# Jenkins failing to call createItem - Unexpected failure HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-job-dsl

We are using Jenkins 1.513 version for our legacy system. It was working fine till the point we decided to upgrade it to 1.532 version. Post upgrade we started getting the below exception from one of our job - which is responsible to create other jenkins job by calling `createItem` API. So we decided to roll back the change and went back to 1.513 but our error doesn't went away.

How I upgraded the jenkins? Downloaded the `jenkins.war` file for 1.532 version and replaced `/var/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war` file, then restarted the jenkins service. Rollback follows the same procedure with just replacing the backup copy of the original `jenkins.war` file.

Am I missing something? Is there any way to fix this?

```
SEVERE: Error while serving http://<jenkins-instance-url>/createItem
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor902.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:288)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:151)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:90)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:111)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:677)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:770)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:583)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:214)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:45)
    at winstone.ServletConfiguration.execute(ServletConfiguration.java:248)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:333)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:376)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:95)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.corsfilter.AccessControlsFilter.doFilter(AccessControlsFilter.java:79)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:98)
    at hudson.plugins.greenballs.GreenBallFilter.doFilter(GreenBallFilter.java:58)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:98)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:87)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:124)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:135)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilter(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ApiTokenFilter.doFilter(ApiTokenFilter.java:64)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:50)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:331)
    at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.processRequest(RequestHandlerThread.java:227)
    at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.run(RequestHandlerThread.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: There is no space issue on jenkins server.